# How to deserialize json with object name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I'm not really sure how to phrase the problem but, I have the following json:

```
{
  "person": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "gender": "M",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  }
}
```

And deserializing using json.net/javascriptserializer(asp.net) I have the following test code:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}


[Test]
public void TestDeserialize() 
{
    string json = @"{""person"":{""first_name"":""John"",""gender"":""M"",""last_name"":""Doe""}}";

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); // asp.net mvc (de)serializer

    Person doe = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(json);
    Person doe1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json); // json.net deserializer

    Assert.AreEqual("John", doe.first_name);
    Assert.AreEqual("John", doe1.first_name);  
}
```

The test method fails, because both are null. Anything wrong with my code to deserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediary class here:

```
public class Model
{
    public PersonDetails Person { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
string json = @"{""person"":{""first_name"":""John"",""gender"":""M"",""last_name"":""Doe""}}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var model = serializer.Deserialize<Model>(json);
Assert.AreEqual("John", model.Person.first_name);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin this works, it just sucks that you need to have an intermediary object.

Comment: You need this intermediary object because of your JSON definition. It's as simple as that. If your JSON did not have the "person" part, then you would not need the object.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the object in the debugger but I suspect you need to test `doe.person.first_name` and `doe1.person.first_name`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
        string json = @"{'first_name':'John','gender':'M','last_name':'Doe'}";           
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
        Person doe = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(json);
```

[EDIT]
Oh wait...perhaps you are not in control of the JSON that you receive and cannot change it. If that's the case then Darin's solution would be what you need.